# At what point is it safe to start using the Wheel of Time companion

Tags: suggested-order, the-wheel-of-time

I have started reading the Wheel of Time series last year and I am now on the fourth book, *The Shadow Rising. There is a lot of info to take in and I enjoy the world building very much.

I have often  seen the Wheel of Time Companion in book stores and I would love to read it as a companion piece, however, I am very fearful of spoilers.

My question is thus, If it is advised to use the The Wheel of Time Companion as a glossary to the books,using it as reference or looking up something I may have forgotten. Or is it best left until after the series?

**Note**: I am unsure if this is a duplicate question as I did not review the suggestion questions. Fear of spoilers being the primary motivation.

Comment: I couldn't find a question of which this one could be a duplicate, so you're safe for the time being :)

Comment: If you need a glossary/ reference, just use the maps and the glossary in the back of the books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not really safe at any point. The information is arranged by subject, not chronological order. For instance, in the section on the characters one of the bits of information they give is status (alive or dead). I'm quite sure that finding out whether or not Rand lived to see the last battle while reading his character description definitely qualifies as a spoiler. In other words, reading even one page could ruin the whole series for you.

Answer (score 1):

While the Companion may not be safe, I found the [Encyclopedia WOT](http://encyclopaedia-wot.org/index.html) a very helpful resource while reading through the series for the first time. If you avoid the top section summary for a given character that you are looking up, there is a section on each character that is written in chronological order of the in-universe timeline. Even if you catch the occasional minor spoiler, you'll probably need **someting** to help, because as the site states there are roughly 2200 characters in the WOT series.